# About fastLink script for data linkage

Tags: r

I am trying to link two datasets using the fastLink package. The items used for the link are date, time, age, and gender, all converted to numerical data (time: 2/11 as 0211, 11:15 as 1115, male arrow, I created the following script.

```
result <- fastLink(dfA = data_2, dfB = data_1, 
                   varnames = c("date", "time", "age", "gender"), 
                   numeric.match = c("date", "time", "age", "gender"), 
                   cut.a. num = 1, cut.p.num = 2.5, 
                   dedupe.matches=TRUE, threshold.match =0.0001, return.all=TRUE)
```

The threshold.match is set to this value because the number of data decreases as the threshold.match is raised above 0.0001.

My questions are, is this the right setting for threshold.match? Also, are there any items missing  in the above script?